# is_open() function in C++ always return 0 value and getLine(myFile, line) does not return anything

Tags: c++, file-io, cygwin, fstream

Trying to read a file in C++ using fstream. 
But the is_open() function always return 0 result and readline() does not read anything. Please see the code snippet below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string line;
    ifstream myfile("D:\xx\xx\xx\xx\testdata\task1.in.1");
    if (myfile.is_open()) {
        while (getline(myfile, line)) {
            cout << line << '\n';
        }
        myfile.close();
    }

    else
        cout << "Unable to open file";

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you think you're opening `D:\<somepath>\testdata\task1.in.1`

but in fact you're trying to open `D:\<somepath><tabulation char>estdata<tabulation char>ask1.in.1` since `\t` is interpreted as a tabulation.

(like `\n` is a newline in `printf("hello world\n");`)

(`\x` is special too BTW that's not the real path or you would have had another error: `error: \x used with no following hex digits` which maybe would have talked to you better!)

You have to escape the backslashes like this:

`D:\\xx\\xx\\xx\\xx\\testdata\\task1.in.1`

Windows also accepts paths like those, more convenient, unless you want to generate batch scripts with `cd` commands or the like that would require backslashes (`/` is used as option switch in batch commands):

`D:/xx/xx/xx/xx/testdata/task1.in.1`

As NathanOliver stated, you can use the raw prefix if your compiler has C++11 mode enabled (or with `--std=c++11`)

`R"(D:\xx\xx\xx\xx\testdata\task1.in.1)"`

Last word: dirty way of getting away with it:

`D:\Xx\Xx\Xx\Xx\Testdata\Task1.in.1`

Using uppercase in that case would work

1. because windows is case insensitive
2. C would let the backslashes as is.

But that's mere luck. A lot of people do that without realizing they're very close to a bug.
BTW a lot of people capitalize windows paths (as seen a lot in this site) because they noticed that their paths wouldn't work with lowercase without knowing why.

Comment: You remember right. I was typing that when you commented. If you only do file I/O you can work this way (also helps for more portable code when switching to Linux, well at least on relative paths or relative include paths).

Comment: `"\Xx"` hack: great!

Comment: Perfect Jean! I missed the \t thing. Thanks a lot. It worked.

Comment: You may also want to use the raw string literal like `R"(D:\xx\xx\xx\xx\testdata\task1.in.1)"`.

Comment: Would be the best solution. I'm editing my post. Does recent C standard support that too?